# When using ZMQ to receive messages, ZMQ always went wrong probability

Tags: c++, centos7, zeromq

When using ZMQ to receive messages, ZMQ always went wrong probability.

My develop environment:

```
zmq version: 4.1.4
server: centos7.0, 8cpu 2.0GHZ
```

code as follow:

```
{
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_PULL);
socket.bind(m_config.m_strIPAndPort);

zmq::pollitem_t pollItems[]= {{socket,0,ZMQ_POLLIN,0}};
int MAX_POLLITEM_NUM = 1;

while ( !m_bStopThread )
{
    try
    {
        zmq::poll(pollItems, MAX_POLLITEM_NUM, -1);
        if( pollItems[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN )
        {
            zmq::message_t zmqMsg;
            bool bRes = socket.recv(&zmqMsg);
            if ( bRes )
            {
                pushMsg((const char *)zmqMsg.data(), zmqMsg.size());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (exception & e)
    {
        const char * pszError = e.what();
        string strErrMsg = "Error : receive cmd from client exception : " + string(pszError);
        qInfo(strErrMsg.c_str());
    }
}
}
```

Stack information of GDB:

```
#0  0x00007fe3366c7277 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fe3366c8968 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fe337ffabb9 in zmq::zmq_abort (
errmsg_=errmsg_@entry=0x7fe33803b71f "check ()") at src/err.cpp:87
#3  0x00007fe3380030eb in zmq::msg_t::size (this=0x7fe320002d00)
at src/msg.cpp:361
#4  0x00007fe3380308f2 in zmq::v2_encoder_t::message_ready (
this=0x7fe2e8008ce0) at src/v2_encoder.cpp:54
#5  0x00007fe338021cc1 in zmq::stream_engine_t::out_event 
(this=0x7fe320002ce0)
at src/stream_engine.cpp:386
#6  0x00007fe338015a76 in zmq::session_base_t::read_activated (
this=0x7fe3200031b0, pipe_=0x7fe2e8008ac0) at src/session_base.cpp:288
#7  0x00007fe337ffbb14 in zmq::io_thread_t::in_event (this=0x1d17100)
at src/io_thread.cpp:85
#8  0x00007fe337ffa36e in zmq::epoll_t::loop (this=0x1d176b0)
at src/epoll.cpp:188
#9  0x00007fe33802b96d in thread_routine (arg_=0x1d17730) at 
    src/thread.cpp:109
#10 0x00007fe337284e25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#11 0x00007fe33678fbad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

When running it at another server with higher frequency cpu(eg. 3.2G),   It works properly.

What should I do?

**Thanks for answers.**

Comment: `ZMQ always went wrong probability.`What does this mean ?

Comment: What's the error you get ?